# Cursor lag or sticky effect on links

Tags: macos, mouse, cursor, links

After upgrading to macOS Sierra I've noticed that my mouse cursor tends to lag, grab or stick to links when traversing over a web page. The effect seems mostly pronounced in Safari but is exhibited in other browsers as well. Anyone experience anything like this and know how to change or disable the effect?

Comment: Same here (especially in Safari) with a trackpad after installing Security Update 2016-003 for El Capitan yesterday. Not only stickiness etc but also spontaneous zoomin' in/out - I turned off all 1-2-3 finger effects!

Comment: @klanomath What exact Macs are you guys using?

Comment: @kal-al MacBook Pro early 2011 (13")

Comment: @klanomath I just installed the security updates on El Capitan in a late 2011 13" MBP (so similar but not exact Mac as you) and have not noticed that problem after a very brief test using Safari. Does it always happen or just sometimes?

Comment: @kal-al After disabling all trackpad gestures it works normally.

Comment: Pure guess... could it be looking up each link against some kind of 'safe browsing' database, or some new hover over feature? (I had my own disastrous day with that security update & I'm not going anywhere near it again:(

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when my cursor size was above normal. Check *System Preferences* > *Accessibility* > *Display*.

Comment: WEEKS that I am wondering what is happening. Thank you so much!